# How to execute code when a folder is opened in Windows 7

Tags: triggers

I want to create a folder that has shortcuts to files from other folders. I always want the folder to contain the most recently modified files from the other folders. I was planning to write some code that would update the shortcuts, but I don't want the people who will be using this folder to have to worry about running the code each time they want the most recent files.

Is there any way that I could trigger the code to run each time a user accesses the folder? I haven't decided what language to write the code in, but I'm familiar with Java, C, and VBA.

Thanks